# Next page with python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Am new to Python and stuck with the 'next page' logic.

I tried while loop & selenium with chrome nothing worked.

Please shed some light in this -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv 

pages = [ 0 , 25 , 50 , 75]
for page in pages:
    source = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/predefined/day_gainers?count=25&offset={}'.format(page)).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source , 'lxml') 

for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    table = soup.find("table",{"class":"W(100%)"})
    thead = table.find("thead").find_all("th")
    table_head = [th.text for th in thead]
    #print(table_head)

    table_body = table.find ("tbody").find_all("tr")
        
with open("report.csv" , "a" , newline="") as csv_file:
        csv_write = csv.writer(csv_file)
        csv_write.writerow(table_head)
        
        for tr in table_body:
            table_data = [td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td') ]
            csv_write.writerow(table_data)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is useful to provide more of a description around what isn't working (even if you think it is there implicitly) e.g. what is happening, what should happen, any error codes and where errors occur.... You can get additional tips from [ask] and [tour] as well as [help].

Answer (score 0):

I think  need to indent your code and its work fine. Here is code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

pages = [ 0 , 25 , 50 , 75]
for page in pages:
    
    source = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/predefined/day_gainers?count=25&offset={}'.format(page)).text
    

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source , 'lxml')


    for link in soup.find_all("a"):
        table = soup.find("table",{"class":"W(100%)"})
        thead = table.find("thead").find_all("th")
        table_head = [th.text for th in thead]
        #print(table_head)

        table_body = table.find ("tbody").find_all("tr")

        with open("report.csv" , "a" , newline="") as csv_file:
                csv_write = csv.writer(csv_file)
                csv_write.writerow(table_head)

                for tr in table_body:
                    table_data = [td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td') ]
                    csv_write.writerow(table_data)
```

**Edit**
For the second for loop getting duplicates value. So remove second for loop. Here is edited code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

pages = [ 0,25,50,75 ]
for page in pages:
    source = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/predefined/day_gainers?count=25&offset={}'.format(page)).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source , 'lxml')

    table = soup.find("table",{"class":"W(100%)"})
    thead = table.find("thead").find_all("th")
    table_head = [th.text for th in thead]
    table_body = table.find ("tbody").find_all("tr")
    with open("report.csv" , "a" , newline="") as csv_file:
            csv_write = csv.writer(csv_file)
            csv_write.writerow(table_head)
            for tr in table_body:
                table_data = [td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td') ]
                csv_write.writerow(table_data)
```

Comment: Thanks, but am getting a lot of duplicates.